# Referring to "this" in Dart JS interop

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-js-interop

I want to implement the following code in Dart:

```
var HelloWorldScene = cc.Scene.extend({
    onEnter:function () {
        this._super();
    }
});
```

My Dart implementation looks like this:

```
class HelloWorldScene {
  HelloWorldScene() {
    var sceneCollectionJS = new JsObject.jsify({ "onEnter": _onEnter});

    context["HelloWorldScene"] = context["cc"]["Scene"].callMethod("extend", [sceneCollectionJS]);
  }

  void _onEnter() {
    context["this"].callMethod("_super");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error when running the code:

> The null object does not have a method 'callMethod'

on the following line:

> context["this"].callMethod("_super", []);

context["this"] seems to be null, so my question is: How do I refer to the "this" variable from Dart?

UPDATE 1:
The full example code can be found on github:
https://github.com/uldall/DartCocos2dTest

Comment: I guess you made a typo: `context[this].callMethod("_super");`(without the quotes).

Comment: Without quotes 'this' would refer to the instance of the HelloWorldScene Dart class. I wish to call _super() on the "this" variable living in the Javascript VM.

Comment: Can you post a complete example. please?

Comment: I'm not familiar with DartJS but I would suggest to set a `debugger;` before the `context["this"].callMethod("_super");` and see what's in `context`.

Comment: @Robert I added the complete example to github.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the Js `this` with [JsFunction.withThis(f)](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:js.JsFunction#id_JsFunction-withThis). With that definition an additionnal argument will be added as first argument. Thus your code should be :

```dart
import 'dart:js';

class HelloWorldScene {
  HelloWorldScene() {
    var sceneCollectionJS =
        new JsObject.jsify({"onEnter": new JsFunction.withThis(_onEnter)});

    context["HelloWorldScene"] =
        context["cc"]["Scene"].callMethod("extend", [sceneCollectionJS]);
  }

  void _onEnter(jsThis) {
    jsThis.callMethod("_super");
  }
}
```

Comment: I now get the following error: `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '_super'`. It seems that it is not the correct "this" I get a hold off.